# Powershell: return XML from function properly

Tags: xml, powershell

I am working on a Powershell script which performs XML manipulation in that it dynamically adds child nodes to an existing XML string. I have an issue to "catch" the return value of the function. I have read and know that there is no such thing as returning a value in Powershell, but still I cannot properly access the manipulated XML.

This is the code:

```
function changeXML{Param ([xml]$xmlCall)

    $newNode = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>123</test>'
    [xml]$newNodeXML = $newNode;

    $node = $newNodeXML.SelectSingleNode("//test");

    $newNode = $xmlCall.ImportNode($node, $true);

    $xmlCall.SelectSingleNode("//request").AppendChild($newnode);

    Write-Host $xmlCall.getType(); # ==> System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Write-Host $xmlCall.innerXML; # This shows the correct XML on the console output

}

$xmlCall = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <request>
      <authentication>xyz</authentication>
    </request>';

#manipulate XML
changeXML -xmlCall $xmlCall;

Write-Host $xmlCall.getType(); # ==> System.String
Write-Host $xmlCall.innerXML; # ==> Empty
```

The code is simplified but actually represents all operations. Hence it may look a bit overcomplicated, but actually I (should) need to do everything as is shown in the example.

My problem is that after the function `changeXML` is called, I cannot access the manipulated XML. When I execute `Write-Host $xmlCall.innerXML` inside the function, it looks fine. But when I execute `Write-Host $xmlCall.innerXML` after the function is finished, it is empty. I know that the problem likely has its root in the fact that the variable `$xmlCall` initially is a string, but then is of type XML inside the function. However, I couldn't find a way to work around this.

**My question is:** How can I access the manipulated `$xmlCall` variable after the `changeXML` function is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$xmlCall` defined in your `param` block only *exists inside the scope of the function*, and you never output the value of `$xmlCall` from your function. To do so, use either `Write-Output`, `return` or simply just leave a reference to `$xmlCall` in the function definition:

```
function Update-XML
{
    param(
        [xml]$xmlCall
    )

    $newNode = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>123</test>'
    [xml]$newNodeXML = $newNode;

    $node = $newNodeXML.SelectSingleNode("//test");

    $newNode = $xmlCall.ImportNode($node, $true);

    # suppress output from AppendChild()
    [void]$xmlCall.SelectSingleNode("//request").AppendChild($newnode)

    # return value of $xmlCall
    return $xmlCall
}
```

---

If you pass an actual `XmlDocument` to the function, you'd find that the original document you pass in will reflect the changes made to it, so a nicer way of designing your function might be to only return the `$xmlCall` when the caller asks for it:

```bsh
function Update-XML
{
    param(
        [xml]$xmlCall,
        [switch]$PassThru
    )

    $newNode = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>123</test>'
    [xml]$newNodeXML = $newNode;

    $node = $newNodeXML.SelectSingleNode("//test");

    $newNode = $xmlCall.ImportNode($node, $true);

    # suppress output from AppendChild()
    [void]$xmlCall.SelectSingleNode("//request").AppendChild($newnode)

    if($PassThru){
        # return value of $xmlCall
        return $xmlCall
    }
}
```

Example use with string input:

```bsh
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><authentication>xyz</authentication></request>'

$updatedXmlDocument = Update-XML $xmlString -PassThru

# now you can reference $updatedXmlDocument.innerXml
```

Example use with an existing `XmlDocument` reference:

```bsh
$xmlDoc = [xml]'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><authentication>xyz</authentication></request>'

Update-XML $xmlDoc

# now $xmlDoc.innerXml reflects the changes made in the function
```

Comment: thanks. that makes perfect sense. just had to tweak my "real" code a bit further and add anoter [void] statement. i had to do this because another statement was outputting something and it "polluted" the returned variable.

Comment: @beta: I suggest forming a habit of `$null = ...` for output suppression; `[void]` definitely works, but situationally requires you to wrap the command in `(...)`; e.g. `$null = 1 + 2` works fine, but `[void] 1 + 2` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are declaring the XML, you are saying it's a string until it enters the function, but when the function leaves the current session still consider it as `String`.

Change your declaration to

```
[xml]$xmlCall = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <request>
      <authentication>xyz</authentication>
    </request>';
```

From there if you output the xml request after the function you will get

```
 $xmlCall.request | Format-List


authentication : xyz
test           : 123
```